# Java Script 2 D Arrays allocation

Tags: javascript

I want to allocate a 2 D Array in Java Script.

I want do some thing similar to this in JavaScript

```
typedef struct
{
   int  itemA,
   int  itemB,
   string testC
} myStruc;

myStruct MyArray [100];
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 6):

```
var arr = []
arr[0] = { "itemA": "A", "itemB": "B", "itemC": "C" }
arr[1] = { "itemA": "A", "itemB": "B", "itemC": "C" }
```

I think you are trying to apply static language constructs to the dynamic and different world of Javascript.  Javascript doesn't really have the notion of arrays in the sense that many languages do.

In Javascript, an array is simpl a special kind of object (itself just a hash) which has a special length property.  The integer "indexes" that you see above (ie, the 0 in arr[0]) are just has lookups.  The special length property is defined to be one greater than the greatest integer key.  In my example above, arr.length is 2.  But if I were to assign:

```
arr[100] = { "itemA": "A", "itemB": "B", "itemC": "C" }
```

Then arr.length would be 101, even though I've done nothing to assign any of the elements from 2 to 99.

Similarly, we generally don't predefine objects like structs in Javascript, and thus anonymous objects will largely accomplish what you want (or use a documented factory function such as in the example from Ken).

"new Array()" isn't necessary as the concise "var a = [];" syntax is quicker. :)

Comment: Interesting.  I had wondered what would happen if you assigned "out of bounds" on an array in js.

Comment: And the construction jsight shows actually allocates an object to every array-element, as the curly braces denotes an object.

But you can access the properties in both object- and array-style notation:

var itemA1 = arr[1]["itemA"];
var itemA1 = arr.1.itemA;

Answer (score 3):

If i have understand you need to dynamically create an array of a specified length filled with your own struct.

In js a struct is an [object Object] like

```
    // typedef struct { type prop1 , ... , type propN } myStructName;
    function myStructName(){}

    myStructName.prototype = {
        'constructor' : myStructname,
        'prop1' : defaultVal1,
        // ...
        'propN' : defaultValN
    };
```

We can make a function who dinamycally create a struct type but is not this case.
Now we just have to create a function that create an array of a specific length filled with all myStruct object instances.
This is my way

```
/*
    Copyrights (c) 2011 - Matteo Giordani < matteo.giordani90@gmail.com >
    MIT-Style License
    typedef struct{ int itemA , int itemB , string testC } myStruct
    myStruct arr[10];
```

```
    JS way

    function myStruct( a , b , c )
        @param  {int}       a
        @param  {int}       b
        @param  {string}    c
        @return {object}
```

*/
    function myStruct(){

`// arguments
    var a = arguments[0] , b = arguments[1] , c = arguments[2];

    // check INT type for argument a
    if( typeof a == "number" && (a + "").indexOf('.') == -1 ){ this['itemA'] = a; }
    // check INT type for argument b
    if( typeof b == "number" && (b + "").indexOf('.') == -1 ){ this['itemB'] = b; }
    // check INT type for argument b
    if( typeof c == "string" /*check for string length?!*/){ this['testC'] = c; }
}

// myStruct prototype
myStruct.prototype = {
    // constructor
    'constructor' : myStruct,
    // default value for itemA
    'itemA' : 0,
    // default value for itemB
    'itemB' : 0,
    // default value for testC
    'testC' : ''
};

/*
    static function defaultLength([, length])
    Set/Get the defaultLength value.
        @param  {unsigned int|void} length
        @return {void|unsigned int}
*/

myStruct.defaultLength = function(){
    // return the default value
    if( arguments.length == 0 ){
        return myStruct._default;
    }else{
    // set the default value
        var l = arguments[0];
        myStruct._default = ( typeof l == "number" && (l + "").indexOf('.') == -1 ) ? Math.abs( l ) : 0;
    }
};

// @var {unsigned int}  myStruct._default = 0
myStruct._default = 0;

/*
    static function makeArray( length )
    @param  {unsigned int}  length  the length of the array
    @return {array}
*/
myStruct.makeArray = function( length ){
    // Check if length is unsigned int
    length = ( typeof length == "number" && (length + "").indexOf('.') == -1 ) ? Math.abs( length ) : myStruct.defaultLength();

    // local array
    var array = [] , i = 0;

    // populate the array
    for( ; i < length; i++){
        array[ i ] = new myStruct();
    }

    // return
    return array;
};

// MAKE IT!
myStruct.defaultLength(10);             // set the default length == 10
var arr = myStruct.makeArray();         // [myStruct, myStruct, myStruct, myStruct, myStruct, myStruct, myStruct, myStruct, myStruct, myStruct]
arr.length;                             // 10
Object.prototype.toString.call( arr );  // [object Array]

/* ANOTHER EXAMPLE */
var arr2 = [];                          // make an empty array
arr2[0] = new myStruct(1,1,'test1');    // make a first myStruct object
arr2[1] = new myStruct(2,2,'test2');    // make a second myStruct object`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want properties for an array of objects, but I may be misinterpreting.

You may just need something like...

```
function Person(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}

var person = new Person("John", "Dough");
```

http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/javascript/inheritance/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
function Sample(value1, value2) {
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
}

var test = new Array();

test[0] = new Sample("a","aa");
test[1] = new Sample("b","bb");
```

PS: There are several ways to accomplish this in Java Script.

Answer (score 1):

If you really like to *allocate* 100 elements array of a particular structure, you can do following:

```
arr = [];

for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
   arr[i] = {itemA: <value>, itemB: <value>, textC: <string>, ... };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are  a few ways of creating arrays in Javascript, the method closest to what you want to do should be:

```
var myArray = new Array("someString1", "someString2", "someString3", ...);
```

You can replace `"someString1"` with actual objects.

You can also use the Array constructor to set up the initial length:

```
var myArray = new Array(5);
myArray[0] = ...;
myArray[1] = ...;
```

Arrays in Javascript are pretty loose actually - you don't even need to define the length before you access an element that would normally be outside the bounds of the array.

Take a look at [the Mozilla documentation on Arrays](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array).